# SQL Server - getting data issue day wise

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `day`, and the columns in this table are `IsMonday` to `IsSunday` and `IsActive`, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

I want to fetch data according to current day.

How we can write a query for that?

I am getting `current day` query as:

```
declare @weekDayName nvarchar(10)

@weekDayName = (select datename(dw, getdate()))
```

My issue is that I pass the only date and check which day is `current day` and `Active`.

Please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only information your table seems to persist is a separate column for each day of the week.  So, the best we can do given the current day is to select the column corresponding to that day:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 1 AND isSunday = 1) OR
    (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 2 AND isMonday = 1) OR
    (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 3 AND isTuesday = 1) OR
    (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 4 AND isWednesday = 1) OR
    (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 5 AND isThursday = 1) OR
    (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 6 AND isFriday = 1) OR
    (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 7 AND isSaturday = 1);
```

Comment: i want to use in where condition and i am using multiple table

Comment: @PramodGehlot Check my updated query.  I think I misunderstood your requirements.